# Android device adb another device

Tags: android, adb

Does anyone know how to make a device adb another device.

i.e

Device1 I create a folder apks and copy and paste 5 apk files.

then I use micro usb to micro usb to connect to another device.

then from device1 i adb all these 5 apk files to device2 
using something like this a guess ?

```
adb install 1.apk & adb install 2apk & adb install 3.apk & adb install 4.apk & adb install 5.apk
```

I know this is possible as I know someone who does it. But their won't reveal how it is done. Thank you

Comment: Root your device1 and put `adb` on that??

Comment: @ Abishek Manoharan do you have any info in how to install adb shell on the rooted device ?, thank you

Comment: shell installed on android device by default , usually `adb ` too , if no you may just adb push adb to device from host

Answer (score -2):

AFAIK, connecting two android devices via USB is meaningless.
You can use adb over tcpip (over WiFi) in order to accomplish this.

Here is what you need to do:

1. Make sure both devices are on the same network. This can be done by connecting them to the same AP, by peering them together using WiFi direct or 
   by setting one of the devices as a hotspot and connecting the second to it.
2. Configure device 2 adbd to work over tcpip (this is done from your desktop shell):

   `adb tcpip <port number>`
3. From device 1 shell run:

   `adb connect <device 2 ip>:<port number>`

   `adb install 1.apk`

   `adb install 2.apk2`

   and so forth...

Comment: thank you for ur reply. Now. What if I have 30 devices I want to install apk over adb. Is there away do use ur example.

Then mean reason I wanted to adb from a device 1 to device 2 using usb is because of portability.

Comment: If you need to install these apps on 30 devices, why not just do it from a pc?

why do you have to do so from an android device?

Comment: because my app connects to the local Network (its restricted) for testing. no internet access or can not have local folder to store the apk. So When I need to make a bug fix. connecting 30 device one at the time and run the project to install the apk, takes long time. But If i was to have it on a device, then i can adb device to device much faster.